# jQuery.validate().form() is always true when loaded only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a question regarding the client-side validation plugin fpr jQuery.
I have the following scenario:

The webapp is an ASP.NET MVC 5 application.
I use AJAX to create a Single Page Application by replacing the **#content** element with the content of another page, if you navigate there.

I also use a _Layout.cshtml file, which 'includes' some Scripts like the **jQuery.validate*** files (validate and validate.unobtrusive).

When a page contains a form, I added the validation - files via

**@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")**

on the page (that contains the form) and then manually handled the click event of the submit-button like this:

```js
    function InitializeForm($scope, jsonCallback) {
        //Setup Validation
        var $form = $('form', $scope);
        var $submitButton = $(':submit', $form);
        $submitButton.click(function (event) {
            let isValid = $form.validate().form();
            if (!isValid)
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            //...
        });

        //...
    }
```

But I thought it is very ugly and not neccessary to reload the validation-script-files again to be able to validate all forms of the page.

I tried several alternatives to avoid loading the files every time. Here are some things I tried to make the validation to work without loading the files for each view:

- Instead of the click eventhandler I tried to just use **$form.validate()** when the document is ready to create a validator (that should handle the request on it's own, right?).
- I tried to use the eventhandler to manually invoke the validation, but even if I keep the existing JS-Code and just remove 
  **@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")**  from the views, the "isValid" is always true. I checked all elements of the form (and the form itself) and they all have the needed data- attributes.
- I also tried to destroy / reset the validator in the click eventhandler, but that also didn't work.

What am i missing, shouldn't it work?

Comment: Check out the documentation:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Comment: The question is imo NOT a duplicate of the mentioned other question. They both are related to jQuery.validate() - but there the similarities end. The documentation of valid() didn't help either - when I use this method instead of the direct call $form.validate.form(), the validation is also true every time